# Apply complicated formula to whole column

Tags: google-sheets

I tried searching for this but to no avail - how can I copy a quite complicated formula through the whole column AND make it apply to rows which might be added to the bottom of the sheet?

The formula is this:

```
    =CONCATENATE(A5,IF(ISERROR(FIND("?",A5,1)),CONCATENATE("?"),CONCATENATE("&")),"utm_campaign=",SUBSTITUTE(B5," ", "%20") ,"&utm_medium=",SUBSTITUTE(C5," ", "%20"),"&utm_source=",SUBSTITUTE(D5," ", "%20"),IF(E5<>"",CONCATENATE("&utm_content=",SUBSTITUTE(E5," ", "%20")),),IF(F5<>"",CONCATENATE("&utm_term=",SUBSTITUTE(F5," ", "%20")),))
```

Basically, what it does is it concatenates data from columns A, B, C, D, E, F with some Google "utm" tags and creates tagged destination link. Along the way it checks for various errors and replaces " " with "%20".

Comment: Why don't you share an example doc with us, so we can have a look?

Comment: Jacob, I could share an example but there's really nothing to it. IMagine you have a number 100 in A1, number 150 in B1 and in C1 a formula =A1+B1. Now, instead of dragging it down the entire C column I wish to make a formula/script that would copy this formula from C1 into every sell in the C column. Also, I'd like the formula to copy to all the rows (column C) that might be inserted at the bottom of the document. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reduce the formula and add `ARRAYFORMULAE` to make it work with ranges.

### Formula

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(ISBLANK(A:A), 
      "", 
      SUBSTITUTE(
        ARRAYFORMULA(
          A:A & 
          IF(ISERROR(FIND("?", A:A, 1)), "?", "&") & 
          "utm_campaign=" & 
          B:B & 
          "&utm_medium=" & 
          C:C & 
          "&utm_source=" & 
          D:D & 
          IF(E:E<>"","&utm_content=","") & 
          E:E & 
          IF(F:F<>"","&utm_term=","") & 
          F:F
        )
      , " ",  "%20"
      )
    )
  )

 copy / paste
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A:A), "", SUBSTITUTE(ARRAYFORMULA(A:A & IF(ISERROR(FIND("?", A:A, 1)), "?", "&") & "utm_campaign=" & B:B & "&utm_medium=" & C:C & "&utm_source=" & D:D & IF(E:E<>"","&utm_content=","") & E:E & IF(F:F<>"","&utm_term=","") & F:F), " ",  "%20")))
```

### Explained

It is not possible to use `CONCATENATE` formulae in combination with `ARRAYFORMULAE`. Therefore we need to go about this differently, by using an `AMPERSAND` to join different strings together. If the concatenated string is prepared and the ranges are chosen, then substitute all empty spaces with `%20`. This, together with an `IF` statement to check column A for presence, is all wrapped inside yet another `ARRAYFORMULA`.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Apply complicated formula to whole column](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DjfMUgJmIuG2mblPkiJteN9EPWgEhqXcUfiF0liTHyk/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: AWE-SOME! It worked like a charm.  I thought I'd have to do this by scripting and I'm just starting with it. IF I decide to do this, should I create custom menu item which with learning it.

Comment: You can create a custom formula to perform the same action...but with less text to type in.